# javascript screen.height

Tags: javascript, web, screen

Tengo un problema, y es que quiero ajustar un elemento de mi web para que ocupe toda la pagina. En un principio pensé

```
elemento.width = screen.width
elemento.heigth = screen.height
```

Y funciona. Pero en el caso de screen.height me da los pixeles de mi pantalla (1080) que INCLUYEN la barra de tareas y la barra de navegación de mi browser (Cosa que hace que mi web tenga una scrollbar para navegar hacia abajo, y no quiero). Hay alguna forma de calcular el tamaño en px de la barra de navegacion y de tareas para restársela al height total? O de eliminar la scrollbar

Comment: con window.innerWidth y window.innerHeight de devuelve el tamaño en px de la ventana del navegador, pero solo de donde estan las págnias, nada de barra de navegacion y otras cosas

Comment: O puedes usar `const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;`. Usar `clientWidth` en el root (el document o el body) devuelve el tamaño total de la web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `window.innerHeight`, de paso te recomiendo que leas [la documentación de window](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window). Yo te recomendaría usar [medidas de longitud relativas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#unidades_de_longitud_relativa) como `height:100%` o `height: 100vh`

```js
console.log("window.innerHeight",window.innerHeight);
console.log("window.screen.height",window.screen.height);
```